# Server GUI hidden

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

When I start up my server and client applications, no errors occur and both operate as expected except my server GUI doesn't appear. It functions properly though. What could be causing the problem? I would appreciate any assistance!

Note: My server's gui was operating perfectly until I tried to implement threads

Edit: I added various System.out.println(jtaResults.getText()); throughout the constructor and the text area had the correct data although the GUI not appearing.

Edit2: in `public void run` the program executes the line `ServerApp gui = new ServerApp();` but never executes `gui.setVisible(true);`
How do i force it to set the gui to visible?

```
public class ServerApp extends javax.swing.JFrame {

int clientNum = 1;
Date dateobj = new Date();
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z YYYY" );

public ServerApp() {

    initComponents();


             try{
                 jtaResults.setText("Server started at " + df.toString() );
                 ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8090,100);
                 while(true){
                     Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                     System.out.println("new socket accepted");
                 ProcessClient client = new ProcessClient(socket, clientNum);

                 System.out.println("new client created");


                 Thread t = new Thread(client);
                 System.out.println("new thread created");
                 t.start();
                 System.out.println("tread started");
                 client.createMessage();
                 System.out.println("client create message invoked");
                 jtaResults.append(client.acceptMessage());
                 System.out.println("accept message appended to server screen");
                 clientNum++;
                // client.createStreams();
                 }
             }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("Multiple connections failed: " + e);
             }
        }

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ServerApp gui = new ServerApp();
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

init components

```
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jtaResults = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jtaResults.setEditable(false);
    jtaResults.setColumns(20);
    jtaResults.setRows(5);
    jtaResults.setText("Server started at: ");
    jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jtaResults);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 404, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 291, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}
```

Comment: can we see the initcomponents?

Comment: I edited my post with the requested code!

Comment: Okay so i don't quite understand jframe and stuff like that but aren't you suppose to set the size of the frame also? so it can show when you set it visible

Comment: I used drag and drop in netbeans to create the GUI so i assume it does that for me?